# Many Links Error When Trying To Build Application

Tags: linker-errors, xcode4.4, libtool-xcode

I was developing and application using Xcode 4.1 build for iOS 4.3, but I want to update my Xcode version, so I downloaded using AppStore, so I can have Xcode 4.4.
Now, when I build my application, the build failed, and I have this error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified, -all_load invalid /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/usr/lib/libz.1.2.3.dylib (No such file or directory) Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1 Apple Mach-O Librarian (libtool) Error Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1

I don't understand why I have that errors, if my application was Ok, Anyone know how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: First thing to do is to "clean" your application.

Comment: I already did it. I clean it and build it again, and still have the same error

Comment: Can you build a "toy" application (from scratch) with the new config?

Comment: I already did it, and have no problem. I also, build an application of a tutorial, and have no problem. I looked for differences in the build settings (because I start my project with Xcode 4.1 for iOS 4.3) and I have Linking->Other linking flags (-all_load -objC), so I delete them, and now just have this error

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/usr/lib/libz.1.2.3.dylib (No such file or directory)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1

Comment: I already solved my problem. Thank you very much. I remove links "-all_load" and "-ObjC", and change libz.1.2.3.dylib for "libz.1.2.5.dylib", because that is for SDK5. Although now my app crashes in some functions, I guess is because the SDK version :/